# Stochastic gradient descent for regression with Shuffle data performs better than unshuffled. Why?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

I am using stochastic gradient descent (SGD) algo for a regression task and train the network for multiple iteration of the input data points. I found that shuffling of the input data gives much better results as compare to unshuffled input data for the same number of iterations. For an example, I am training the network for learning the "Square" function for the input range between [-1,1] with total of 100 points and 500 iterations. Therefore total training points would be 100*500 and if I shuffle all these training points system performs much better.

Could anybody please suggests what is the maths behind it? Why shuffling of the inputs perform better? Or any suggestion for reference papers, which explains how stochsticity in the training helps.

Thanks.

Comment: did you figure out any why ? I am seeing similar issue for my temporal data. My intuition is that SGD tries to get an estimate of the actual gradient and over many samples that averages out to the actual gradient of the entire training data. If you don't shuffle data the gradients are very noisy estimators for the actual full batch gradient descent but shuffling helps. Ideally with decaying learning rate and more iteration both should ultimately figure out the same minima

Answer (score 0):

Because SGD works by making large adjustments based on each sample encountered and then makes subsequent smaller and smaller adjustments with the remaining samples, the order of the samples matters. This is especially true if the model is encountering only positive or only negative samples for the first few iterations.

Comment: Thanks Danny. In my system, cost function (error surface) is convex and learning rate is constant. Learning weights are updated each time with fixed amount. Since learning rate is constant theoretically system should reach to same minima in both cases (shuffling and without shuffling). Isn't it or am I missing anything?

Comment: If the learning rate is too high it may bounce around the optimum (over correct). Can you try a smaller learning rate and a greater number of iterations?

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggest, stochastic gradient descent updates the parameter vector of the Neural Network (NN) with the STOCHASTIC gradient of the loss function.

A stochastic gradient is an "[unbiased estimation](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-S15/scribes/25-fast-stochastic-scribed.pdf)" of the true gradient. In other words, a stochastic gradient is a random variable whose expected value is equal to the "true" gradient.

In NN, the gradient is the gradient of the loss function. Fortunately, the loss function is linear, and it is thus the average of the loss function computed at each sample.

When we take one sample and we compute the gradient of the loss function there, the value we get can be seen as an estimate of the true gradient. Now, if your samples are ordered in a certain way, the sequence of loss functions computed on them are not "unbiased".

To recap, to apply stochastic gradient descent, the samples must be taken such that they are independently thrown from a probability distribution, such that the gradient of the loss function computed on each of them "seems" an unbiased estimate of the true loss function.